# Splitting Columns in Pandas DataFrame by a Specific String

Tags: pandas

I read a .txt file into a pandas dataframe and have created a single column with the following values.

```
age\t\t\t\t\t\tAAGE
class of worker\t\t\t\tACLSWKR
industry code\t\t\t\t\tADTIND
occupation code\t\t\t\tADTOCC
```

I would like to split this column into two separate columns with values split at the \t separator. How can I do this?

In this example I would get the following DataFrame:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| age | AAGE |
| class of worker | ACLSWKR |
| industry code | ADTIND |
| occupation code | ADTOCC |

Comment: `\t` is a tabulation or two characters `\ ` and `t`?

Comment: @Corralien It is a tabulation in the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

\t+ for multiple tabs:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="/path/to/file/a_text_file.txt",
    names=["A header", "Another header"],
    sep="\t+",
    engine="python"
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          A header Another header
0              age           AAGE
1  class of worker        ACLSWKR
2    industry code         ADTIND
3  occupation code         ADTOCC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sep='\t'` as parameter of [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) or [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_table('data.txt', sep=r'\t+', engine='python',
                   header=None, names=['A header', 'Another header'])
print(df)

# Output
          A header Another header
0              age           AAGE
1  class of worker        ACLSWKR
2    industry code         ADTIND
3  occupation code         ADTOCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df['col'].str.split(r'\t+', expand=True)
 .set_axis(['A header', 'Another header'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
          A header Another header
0              age           AAGE
1  class of worker        ACLSWKR
2    industry code         ADTIND
3  occupation code         ADTOCC
```